# Getting "No Firebase App has been created" after upgrading react native to 0.61

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

Finished upgrading react native app from 0.59 to 0.61 and when trying to run the app on android getting the following error. React native firebase version is 6.0.3.

If I read from the docs correctly the default app is created automatically so I assume I've missed something while upgrading react native or react-native-firebase.

[image]

not getting the error ios...